HTTP server behavior and REST API specification for unsupported operations
I have a specification of some REST API, and I am also developing some implementation of the corresponding API.
The question arises, what HTTP status code should my implementation return for operations from the specification that are not implemented yet (I can't decide between 405 and 501)? And should I display the corresponding responses in the OpenAPI specification?

Both 405 and 501 are meant in regard to the HTTP request method. So unless you are talking about something like "my API supports GET request as of right now, but POST request handling will be added later", IMHO they are both the wrong choice.

Hello @C3roe for example, I am implementing an S3 API and at the moment I have not implemented all the operations, but in the future I may implement some of them. What HTTP code would be preferable in this case? Should I correct the original specification taking into account these possible answers?

Yeah, you can use the responses section of the operation to indicate that the endpoint will return a 501 Not Implemented response
paths:
  /ex:
    get:
      summary: Example operation
      description: This operation is not yet implemented.
      responses:
        '501':
          description: Not implemented
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  error:
                    type: string
                    example: "This operation is not implemented yet."

Response body:
{
  "error": "This operation is not implemented yet."
}  

another example:
x-api-status: "planned"
x-expected-release: "v2.0"

/get:
  summary: Example operation
  description: |
    This operation is currently not implemented. 
    Planned for future release in **v2.0**.
  x-api-status: "planned"
  x-expected-release: "v2.0"
  responses:
    '501':
      description: Not implemented
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/ErrorResponse'

A sandbox:
responses:
  '200':
    description: Stub response for testing
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          type: object
          properties:
            data:
              type: string
              example: "Stubbed response: feature not yet implemented."

example for 405 invalid http methods:
responses:
  '405':
    description: Method not allowed
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/ErrorResponse'

endpoints:
 {
  "version": "v1.0",
  "endpoints": {
    "/example": {
      "methods": ["GET"],
      "status": "not implemented"
    },
    "/users": {
      "methods": ["GET", "POST"],
      "status": "implemented"
    }
  }
}

